# Problem with jQuery Validation Plugin submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I am using "Inline Form Validation Engine 1.6.2, jQuery plugin" to validate form.
But i want that on click of a link i.e..

```
<a href="#">Click here to submit</a>
```

it should validate. as my form do not have submit button..
Please help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
$('a#submit').click(function(){
   $('#form-id').submit();
})


<a href="#" id="submit">Click here to submit</a>
```

I won't suggest to have your form without any submit button... because you are screwed when javascript is disabled in a browser.